# Side by side maps with tmap in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tmap

I am trying to compare two thematic maps using tmap package in Shiny. However I got an error argument length zero. Also I want to plot these two maps from selecting Shinyinput panel.I mean from 4 inputs 2 combinations of 4 plot can be drawn.The plot must be drawn when the length of input$hafta is equal to 2. I send you the data type and code that I wrote.

PS: I tried with using facets in tmap however as far as I found out that shiny does not support it.
Thank you

`str(turcov@data)`

```
'data.frame':   81 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ NAME_1   : chr  "Adana" "Adıyaman" "Afyon" "Ağrı" ...
 $ GID_0    : chr  "TUR" "TUR" "TUR" "TUR" ...
 $ NAME_0   : chr  "Turkey" "Turkey" "Turkey" "Turkey" ...
 $ GID_1    : chr  "TUR.1_1" "TUR.2_1" "TUR.3_1" "TUR.4_1" ...
 $ VARNAME_1: chr  "Seyhan" "AdÄ±yaman" "Afyonkarahisar" "AÄŸri|KarakÃ¶se" ...
 $ NL_NAME_1: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ TYPE_1   : chr  "Il" "Il" "Il" "Il" ...
 $ ENGTYPE_1: chr  "Province" "Province" "Province" "Province" ...
 $ CC_1     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ HASC_1   : chr  "TR.AA" "TR.AD" "TR.AF" "TR.AG" ...
 $ sub4     : num  41.2 116.2 38.4 19 123.1 ...
 $ mart1    : num  63 154.6 47.5 22.2 173.5 ...
 $ fark     : num  52.8 33.1 23.6 16.9 41 ...
 $ kategori : Factor w/ 2 levels "artış","azalış": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ mart2    : num  63 154.6 47.5 22.2 173.5 ...
 $ mart3    : num  61.6 169.8 47.4 41.5 214.4 ...


library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(spdep)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(tmap)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("hafta", "Hafta seçiniz:", choices=c("sub4","mart1","mart2","mart3") 
,selected=NULL,multiple=TRUE,selectize = TRUE)),
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("İki hafta il sınıflandırma karşılaştırması", 
                         tmapOutput("map1", width = "100%", height = 800)), 
                tabPanel("Artış-azalış ve Artış-azalış yüzdeleri", 
                         tmapOutput("map2", width = "100%", height = 800)),
                tabPanel("İl ve komşuları haftalık vaka trendi", 
                         plotlyOutput("map3", width = "100%", height = 800))
                
              )
        )))
server <- function(input, output) {

output$map1<-renderTmap({ print(input$hafta)
breaks<-c(0,20,50,100,Inf)
renk=c("blue","yellow","orange","red")
tmap1<-tmap_mode("view")+
    tm_shape(turcov) +
    tm_fill(input$hafta[1],breaks = breaks, 
            title=c(" İllere göre 100 binde vaka sayıları(input$hafta[1])"),palette = renk) +
    tm_borders() +
    tm_text("NAME_1")
  
tmap2<-tmap_mode("view")+
    tm_shape(turcov) +
    tm_fill(input$hafta[2],breaks = breaks, 
            title=c(" İllere göre 100 binde vaka sayıları(input$hafta[1])"),palette = renk) +
    tm_borders() +
    tm_text("NAME_1")

  tmap_arrange(tmap1,tmap2,ncol=2)
   })
  } 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In r with the same data set I achieved side by side plots by using tmap package and tmaparrange. turcov is a spatialpolygonsdataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
#UI
tabPanel("İki hafta il sınıflandırma karşılaştırması", fluidRow(
                        column(6, tmapOutput("map1", width = "100%", height = 800)),
                        column(6, tmapOutput("map2", width = "100%", height = 800))))
#SERVER
output$map1<-renderTmap({ 
breaks<-c(0,20,50,100,Inf)
renk=c("blue","yellow","orange","red")
tmap1<-tmap_mode("view")+
tm_shape(turcov) +
tm_fill(input$hafta[1],breaks = breaks, 
        title=c(" İllere göre 100 binde vaka sayıları(input$hafta[1])"),palette = 
renk) +
tm_borders() +
tm_text("NAME_1")
output$map2<-renderTmap({ 
tmap1<-tmap_mode("view")+
tm_shape(turcov) +
tm_fill(input$hafta[2],breaks = breaks, 
        title=c(" İllere göre 100 binde vaka sayıları(input$hafta[1])"),palette = 
renk) +
tm_borders() +
tm_text("NAME_1")
})
```

Well as long as I understand shiny does not support facets type maps, I did the plotting according to suggestion of tmap by indivudual plots by dvivding the plotouput into two columns. That solves my issue.